# vSphere error when powering virtual machine

Tags: esxi

Successfully installed VMWARE and vSphere on local machine. Also added vmx file from datastore to inventory. The problem is when powering the virtual machine encountered this error:

```
Failed to start the virtual machine (error-18)
```

Error Stack Trace

```
This virtual machine is not configured according to rules specified in /etc/vmware/configrules
Invalid value "/disk2/vmserver/hdisks/hpbsni_3ndDisk_tmpDB.vmdk" for configuration key "scsi0:4.fileName". The value was not accepted by rule "Virtual SCSI Devices".

Invalid value "/disk2/vmserver/hdisks/hpbsni_2ndDisk.vmdk" for configuration key "scsi0:3.fileName". The value was not accepted by rule "Virtual SCSI Devices".
```

What does this error mean and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file in ESX called: /etc/vmware/configrules that specifies (in regular expression format) rules for which devices can be attached, where they can be attached from, etc.  By default, I believe that this file only allows virtual SCSI devices to come from a path beginning with /vmfs.  Since your path begins with /disk2, you either have to add another configrule or edit the existing one to allow /disk2 in addition to /vmfs.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks jkovba, i saw the configrules script but didn't really understand what it meant at first but eventually just decided to copy every VM image in one folder and it worked. So you were right about your explanation too bad I didn't see this two days ago. :)

Comment: No problem dimas!  I'm sorry you didn't see it earlier but glad you got it working.  Would you mind up-voting the answer in the event that it might help someone else?  Thanks!